# Kotlin Recyclerview change item color onClick

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewbinding, android-diffutils

i have a Recyclerview adapter in Kotlin and when i click it change the color to Red but if i click another item, the previous item still have the Red color. How to make the logic when the item click it will change Red and when click another item it will back to default color and new item become Red.

this is the adapter

```
class CategoryAdapter(private val onClick: OnClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

private val diffCallBack = object: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CategoryResponse>(){
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: CategoryResponse, newItem: CategoryResponse): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CategoryResponse, newItem: CategoryResponse): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

private val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this,diffCallBack)
fun submitData(value: List<CategoryResponse>?) = differ.submitList(value)

interface OnClickListener {
    fun onClickItem (data: CategoryResponse)
}

inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ListCategoryHomeBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun bind (data: CategoryResponse){
        binding.tvCategoryHome.text = data.name
        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            onClick.onClickItem(data)
            binding.tvCategoryHome.setTextColor(Color.RED) <-- this item when i click another item, previous item stay red. i want to make the previous item back to default color
        }
    }
}
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val inflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    return ViewHolder(ListCategoryHomeBinding.inflate(inflate,parent,false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val data = differ.currentList[position]
    data.let {
        holder.bind(data)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return differ.currentList.size
  }
}
```

this is the handle on fragment

```
categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(object: CategoryAdapter.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClickItem(position: Int, data: CategoryResponse) {
            val status = "available"
            val search = ""
            viewModel.getProductBuyer(categoryId = data.id.toString(), status = status, search = search)
        }
    })
    binding.rvCategoryHome.adapter = categoryAdapter

   viewModel.showCategory.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
        categoryAdapter.submitData(it)
    }
```

Comment: You need to track every item clicked by adding a field( It can be boolean) in category response. When you click item, this field would track which item is clicked, change button color in list  accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep track of the clicked item position and handle the selected item:

1. Add a field to your data model:

```
data class CategoryResponse(
    // other fields,
    isSelected: Boolean = false
)
```

2. Remove this line:

```
binding.tvCategoryHome.setTextColor(Color.RED) <-- this item when i click another item, previous item stay red. i want to make the previous item back to default color
```

3. Pass the item position witch clicked:

```
interface OnClickListener {
    fun onClickItem (position: Int, data: CategoryResponse)
}

binding.root.setOnClickListener {
     onClick.onClickItem(adapterPosition, data) // <= don't forget this
}
```

4. In your fragment(or activity) handle the click listener:

```
class Fragment: Fragment {
    val adapter = CategoryAdapter(
        onClick = { position, data ->
            val currentList = adapter.currentList.toMutableList()
            currentList.forEach {
                isSelected = false
            }

            currentList[position].isSelected = true

            adapter.submitList(currentList)
        }
    )
}
```

5. Handle the **isSelected** field in adapter

```
inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ListCategoryHomeBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun bind (data: CategoryResponse){
        binding.tvCategoryHome.text = data.name
        if(data.isSelected) {
            binding.tvCategoryHome.setTextColor(Color.RED)
        } else {
            binding.tvCategoryHome.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
        }
        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
           //....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tysm for your help! but im facing some error when the handle the onClick in fragment, can you help? i updated my code question, you can check it. thank you!